# Big-O scaling - validation and representation (case: uniqueness of a list)

Tags: python, list, big-o

I've three different methods to check the uniqueness of entries to a list with theoretically different scaling of O(N), O(N log N) and O(N**2), whereas N is the length of the list.

I do understand why these methods SHOULD scale like O(N), O(N log N) and O(N**2), but I fail to prove it numerically.

The idea was simply to run each method multiple times with random list entries and varying length. Then plot the times vs list length (i.e. N). I expected that the worst case for each method/N should SOMEWHAT scale like the theoretical prediction, but it doesn't.

The code:

```
import time
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#O(N**2) - each loop is O(N)
def is_unique1(alist):
    for i in range(len(alist)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(alist)):
            if alist[i] == alist[j]:
                return False
    return True

#O(N log N) - as sort() is O(N log N)
def is_unique2(alist):
    copy = list(alist)
    copy.sort()
    for i in range(len(alist)-1):
        if copy[i] == copy[i+1]:
            return False
    return True    

#O(N) - as set is O(N)
def is_unique3(alist):
    aset = set(alist)
    return len(aset) == len(alist)


times = []
lengths = []
scale = 1.5

for i in range(1,10):
    print('range:',10**i,'to',10**(i+1),'values calc:',int(10**(i/scale)))

for j in range(1,10):
    for i in range(1,int(10**(j/scale))):
        random.seed(42)
        a = str(random.randint(10**j,10**(j+1)))
        start = time.time()
        is_unique3(a)
        end = time.time()
        times.append(end-start)
        lengths.append(len(a))


print(min(times),max(times))

plt.scatter(lengths,times,s=5)
plt.ylabel('process time (s)')
plt.xlabel('N (length of list)')
plt.title('is_unique3')
plt.grid()
plt.ylim(0.9*min(times),1.1*max(times))
#plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

the results:

[image: Method 1 - scaling should be O(N**2)]

[image: Method 2 - scaling should be O(N log N)]

[image: Method 3 - scaling should be O(N)]

Unfortunately I can't see a correspondence between the theoretical expectation and the numerical evaluation at all.

Is it just illusionary to think one could achieve this? Is my way to do so wrong? Do I have to check EVERY possible list entry to get a correct scaling?

I`m puzzled and would appreciate any hint...

######  EDIT

Thanks for the comments! I changed how I gather the times per process and decided to take an average per (now) 100 runs per list length. I tried to take the maximum time per 100 runs but the results looked still random. The adapted code snippet:

```
import time
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#O(N**2) - each loop is O(N)
def is_unique1(alist):
    for i in range(len(alist)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(alist)):
            if alist[i] == alist[j]:
                return False
    return True

#O(N log N) - as sort() is O(N log N)
def is_unique2(alist):
    copy = list(alist)
    copy.sort()
    for i in range(len(alist)-1):
        if copy[i] == copy[i+1]:
            return False
    return True    

#O(N) - as set is O(N)
def is_unique3(alist):
    aset = set(alist)
    return len(aset) == len(alist)

times = []
lengths = []
times_mean = []
#times_max = []

for j in range(500,10000,1000):
    lengths.append(j)
    for i in range(1,100):
        a = []
        for i in range(1,j):
            a.append(random.randint(0,9))
        start = time.perf_counter()
        is_unique2(a)
        end = time.perf_counter()
        times.append(end-start)
    times_mean.append(np.mean(times))
    #times_max.append(np.max(times))

#print(min(times),max(times))
#print(len(lengths),len(times_mean))

plt.scatter(lengths,times_mean,s=5, label='mean')
#plt.scatter(lengths,times_max,s=5, label='max')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.ylabel('process time (s)')
plt.xlabel('N (length of list)')
plt.title('is_unique2')
plt.grid()
plt.ylim(0.9*min(times_mean),1.1*max(times_mean))
#plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

and the results:

[image]
[image]
[image]

While method 2 and 3 look like they would scale as O(N) or O(N log N) somewhat - I hope not by accident - method 1 still looks rubbish and not even close to O(N**2). Actually I expected this method, as a double loop, to be worst by a mile.

Am I still missing something more general?

Comment: having seen your updated code, the first graph reflects the fact that the propability of a list with numbers 0 to 9  in 1000 is 0  and the probability of finding a duplicate first and short-circuiting at a lower index is higher, the bigger your list.   You need a bigger sample of data than just numbers from 0..9

Comment: perhaps a better sample is just shuffling the list of numbers of 1..n and introducing one equal with low probability say 1/n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only going up to length 10, by increments of 1. At that short an input, you're still largely covered by fixed overhead, and the distinction between adjacent values is fairly small (`n` vs. `n log n` won't show up clearly for adjacent values in any event). Try running your tests for input sizes of 100, followed by repeated doubling (200, 400, 800, etc.) if you want to get beyond fixed overheads that swamp visible results, and with enough work difference to show up clearly even with minor interpreter performance jitter (exacerbated by using `time.time()` rather than a more appropriate timing mechanism [like `time.perf_counter` or the like](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter)).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I adapted the code and it helped out to some extent. Still reproducing an O(N**2) scaling for the one method seems still far off.

Comment: @Nikolaij: You realize your `O(n**2)` solution benefits most from short-circuiting, right? You'll only see the big-O behavior you expect when the input is in fact unique (or the non-unique elements first appear *very* late in the list). The `n log n` and `n` solutions both do all of their most algorithmically expensive work completely before they begin looking for duplicates, so their times would be more consistent.

Comment: Very true. I had not fully realised up to now.

Answer (score 1):

To improve your experiment you should use the same dataset for evaluating all functions for all lengths.  At the moment you're generating one new data set for each length of n you want to test and for every function that you want to test.  This will lead to inconclusive results.

Furthermore the Big o only gives you an upper bound limit for your functions not an exact number, it may be lower (in your function if all elements are already unique) but never above the upper bound.